# Como activar el foco de un elemento del listbox en tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

tengo un programa en tkinter, que al realizar una búsqueda, hago que me seleccione un elemento del listbox, el que ha encontrado, os pongo una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el cuadro marcado con rojo, del entry y el listbox, me selecciona el elemento del listbox que ha encontrado, pero no me marca el foco en ese elemento, si nos fijamos me marca el foco en el último elemento como se marca en la línea roja.

Logro que lo seleccióne así.

```
self.DESVfr1_listbox.selection_set(indice)
```

Código completo de la función buscar, es esta..

Es un rollo, jijiji me funciona la busquéda, pero si me dais ideas yo acepto.

```
def buscar_Modulos(self, event=None):
        try:
            valor_aBuscar = event
            clave_Buscado = [n for n in listClave if valor_aBuscar.upper().strip() in n]
            modulo_Buscado = [n for n in listModulo if valor_aBuscar.strip() in n]
            if len(clave_Buscado) <= 1:
                clave_Buscado = str(clave_Buscado).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","")
            else:
                clave_Buscado = ""
            if len(modulo_Buscado) <= 1:
                modulo_Buscado = str(modulo_Buscado).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","")
            else:
                modulo_Buscado = ""
            # ## --------- OBTENER MODULO POR CLAVE O MODULO -------------- ## //TODO "definir si buscar por clave o modulo"
            if len(clave_Buscado) == 0 and len(modulo_Buscado) == 0:
                self.limpiar_Widgets()
                self.DESVfr1_listbox.select_clear(ANCHOR)
                mb.showerror("ERROR","Esta vacio o no existe el modulo.\nPrueba a buscar por CLAVE o el MODULO completo")
            elif len(clave_Buscado) != 0:
                with open(path_modulo.format(asigne_Ciente)) as g:
                    data = []
                    data = json.load(g)
                    for md in data:
                        if clave_Buscado in md['clave']:
                            modulo_Encontrado = md['modulo']
                            ## --- LIMPIAR ------------------------------------- ##                      
                            self.limpiar_Widgets()
                            ## ------------------------------------------------- ##
                            self.asignarValor_aWidgets(md)
                    self.DESVfr1_listbox.selection_clear(0, tk.END)        
                    modulo_ListBox = self.DESVfr1_listbox.get(0, tk.END)
                    indice = modulo_ListBox.index(modulo_Encontrado)
                    self.DESVfr1_listbox.selection_set(indice)
            else:
                data = []
                with open(path_modulo.format(asigne_Ciente)) as g:
                    data = json.load(g)
                    for md in data:
                        if modulo_Buscado in md['modulo']:
                            modulo_Encontrado = md['modulo']
                            ## --- LIMPIAR ------------------------------------- ##                      
                            self.limpiar_Widgets()
                            ## ------------------------------------------------- ##
                            self.asignarValor_aWidgets(md)
                    self.DESVfr1_listbox.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
                    modulo_ListBox = self.DESVfr1_listbox.get(0, tk.END)
                    indice = modulo_ListBox.index(modulo_Encontrado)
                    self.DESVfr1_listbox.selection_set(indice)
            self.DESVfr1_listbox.focus()
        except:
            self.limpiar_Widgets()
            self.DESVfr1_listbox.select_clear(ANCHOR)
            mb.showerror("ERROR","Esta vacio o no existe el modulo.\nPrueba a buscar por CLAVE o el MODULO completo")
```